# How to get values of multiple aliases without introducing callback hell in Cypress?

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

Say I want to retrieve the values of two Cypress aliases and use it in my test case. How do I do so without nesting them in the following manner?

```
cy.get('@alias1')
    .then((alias1) => {
        cy.get('@alias2').then((alias2) => {
            someFunctionThatUsesBothAliases(alias1, alias2);
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
it('test', () => {
    cy.wrap('foo').as('foo');
    cy.wrap('bar').as('bar');
    cy.wrap('baz').as('baz');

    const values = [];
    cy.get('@foo').then( val => {
        values.push(val);
        return cy.get('@bar');
    }).then( val => {
        values.push(val);
        return cy.get('@baz');
    }).then( val => {
        values.push(val);
        someFunc(...values);
    });
});
```

Or you can use this helper I cobbled together (put it in your `support/index.js`):

```js
const chainStart = Symbol();
cy.all = function ( ...commands ) {
    const _           = Cypress._;
    const chain       = cy.wrap(null, { log: false });
    const stopCommand = _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
        attributes: { chainerId: chain.chainerId }
    });
    const startCommand = _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
        attributes: { chainerId: commands[0].chainerId }
    });
    const p = chain.then(() => {
        return _( commands )
            .map( cmd => {
                return cmd[chainStart]
                    ? cmd[chainStart].attributes
                    : _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
                        attributes: { chainerId: cmd.chainerId }
                    }).attributes;
            })
            .concat(stopCommand.attributes)
            .slice(1)
            .flatMap( cmd => {
                return cmd.prev.get('subject');
            })
            .value();
    });
    p[chainStart] = startCommand;
    return p;
}
```

and use it like so:

```js
it('test', () => {

    cy.wrap('one').as('one');
    cy.wrap('two').as('two');
    cy.wrap('three').as('three');

    cy.all(
        cy.get(`@one`),
        cy.get(`@two`),
        cy.get(`@three`)
    ).then( values => {
        someFunc(...values);
    });
});
```

Comment: What if we are using typescript? `all` then does not exist on `cy` type defs.

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/915#issuecomment-568037175

Answer (score 18):

#### Update for Cypress v12

The code @KondasamyJayaraman refers to appears to be broken, I see it relies on internal Cypress implementation from about 5 years ago.

Here is a simpler one-line version which uses a standard Cypress custom command:

```js
it('custom command to get all alias values', () => {

  Cypress.Commands.add('aliases', function(aliasNames) { 
    return aliasNames.map(a => this[a])
  })

  cy.wrap('a').as('foo');
  cy.wrap('b').as('bar');
  cy.wrap('c').as('baz');

  cy.aliases(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']).then(values => {
    expect(values).to.deep.eq(['a', 'b', 'c'])
  })
})
```

Answer (score 8):

*this.** notation can be used to access multiple aliases within a single code block:

```js
    cy.wrap('foo').as('foo');
    cy.wrap('bar').as('bar');
    cy.wrap('baz').as('baz');

    cy.then(function () {
      cy.log(this.foo + this.bar + this.baz)
    })
```

See [this article](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/avoid-cypress-pyramid-of-doom/) for details

Comment: So good! Vote this up!

Comment: `.then()` needs to be chained off another command, so `cy.wrap('baz').as('baz').then(function () {...})`.

Comment: Yep, the docs says so. 
However, it actually works okay without any previous command.

Answer (score 7):

One different solution which is custom developed by [Mr. Nicholas Boll](https://github.com/NicholasBoll), where you will get aliases as an array using custom commands `createAlias/ getAliases`,

```
// get many aliases - API is similar to Promise.all
cy.getAliases([getFoo, getBar, getOne]).then(([foo, bar, one]) => {
  foo // string
  bar // string
  one // number
  console.log(foo, bar, one) // logs 'foo', 'bar', 1
})
```

Here is the complete details in his blog - https://medium.com/@NicholasBoll/cypress-io-making-aliases-type-safe-b6f5db07d580

Code reference - https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-example-todomvc/tree/feat/type-safe-alias

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the values array used above but I do the following:

```
// Make all data available in one alias:
    const testData = {};
    cy.get('@data1').then((data1) => {
      testData.data1 = data1;
    });
    cy.get('@data2').then((data2) => {
      testData.data2 = data2;
    });
    cy.get('@data3').then((data3) => {
      testData.data3 = data3;
    });
    cy.wrap(testData).as('testData');
```

Then when you need the data:

```
cy.get('@testData').then((testData) => {
   const { data1, data2, data3 } = testData;
   ...
});
```