# Gather results from multiple cypress promisses

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is it possible in Cypress.io to gather results of multiple assertions inside `.then` construction so that results can be used outside `.then`?

Based on below example - if I have some pages that I would like to smoke-test (to check eg. if code is different than 404) how to gather information about them? How to verify results all together in one smoke test?

Please look at this simple piece of code that shows the problem:

```
describe('Smoke tests for some pages', () => {
    it('should be able to view page that was loaded correctly', () => {
      // Arrange:
      const pageAddressList = [
        'https://en.wikipediaaa.org',
        'https://en.wikipedia.org'];
      const errors = Array();

      // Act:
      pageAddressList.forEach((pageAddress) => {
        cy.request(pageAddress).then((response) => {
            // check response and add some error to errors if needed
        })

      });
      // Assert:
      // check if errors is empty
    });
});
```

1. Is above approach correct?
2. Should there be separate tests for each page?
3. What if I have 50+ pages to check?
4. What is best approach in Cypress.io in such case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT 2:** This solution was written for Cypress ~3.6.0 or thereabouts so it's possible that newer versions of Cypress work very differently internally, even if you fix some superficial incompatibilities of this code.

**EDIT:** often someone suggests using `Promise.all`, which is not a correct solution. Cypress chainer objects aren't [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com)-compatible, they simply appear to be promises because they implement `.then` interface. That's why `Promise.all` is able to consume an array of chainer objects, but that's it. The resolution values passed to `Promise.all().then` callback is not going to be what you expect (see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/915).

You can use a helper I've suggested [in a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55313313/927631):

```js
// put this in cypress/support/index.js

const chainStart = Symbol();
cy.all = function ( ...commands ) {
    const _           = Cypress._;
    const chain       = cy.wrap(null, { log: false });
    const stopCommand = _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
        attributes: { chainerId: chain.chainerId }
    });
    const startCommand = _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
        attributes: { chainerId: commands[0].chainerId }
    });
    const p = chain.then(() => {
        return _( commands )
            .map( cmd => {
                return cmd[chainStart]
                    ? cmd[chainStart].attributes
                    : _.find( cy.queue.commands, {
                        attributes: { chainerId: cmd.chainerId }
                    }).attributes;
            })
            .concat(stopCommand.attributes)
            .slice(1)
            .flatMap( cmd => {
                return cmd.prev.get('subject');
            })
            .value();
    });
    p[chainStart] = startCommand;
    return p;
}
```

usage:

```js
it('test', () => {
    const urls = [
        'https://en.wikipediaaa.org',
        'https://en.wikipedia.org'
    ];

    cy.all(
        ...urls.map(url => cy.request(url))
    ).then(responses => {
        responses.forEach( resp => {
            expect(resp.status).to.eq(200);
        });
    });
});
```

That being said, you can also do this:

```js
const urls = [
    'https://en.wikipediaaa.org',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org'
];

let passes = 0;

urls.forEach( url => {
    cy.request(url).then( resp => {
        if ( resp.status === 200 ) passes++;
    });
});

cy.then(() => {
    expect(passes).to.eq(urls.length);
});
```

The `cy.all` helper atop is really useful if you want to access the results without having to keep around globals and accessing them from a `cy.then()` callback --- but like I've shown in the last example, everything can be worked around using just vanilla cypress.

Or, if you don't need responses at all, you can simply do:

```js
const urls = [
    'https://en.wikipediaaa.org',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org'
];
urls.forEach( url => {
    cy.request(url).its('status').should('eq', 200);
});
```

Comment: I really love the simplicity of the second solution!

Comment: Note that assigning a returned value is considered anti pattern in Cypress

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for this; I get an error so I'll try to avoid `cy.all`, for now...

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')` referring to this part:
`....  .concat(stopCommand.attributes)`

Comment: I get also `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')`
@TheRedPea did you find a solution?

Comment: Note that this was written a long time ago, and Cypress may work differently now (edited the post to reflect this).

Comment: @dwelle now that you've written that, no wonder it doesn't work, we are now in Cypress 10. something epoch. I mean it's ridiculous that they don't have that functionality in the framework, more ridiculous is that building a custom promise.all which works in JS does not work with Cypress.

Answer (score 4):

- Can gather multiple results from cy.requests?

You can collect them all and act when only all responses are ready with **Cypress.Promise.all**

```
  it.only('Gathering results', () => {
    const urls = ['https://google.com',
      'https://en.wikipedia.org']
    const requests = urls.map(url => {
      console.log(`a request sent to  ${url}`)
      return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
        cy.request(url).then(resopnse => {
          console.log(`'Response from ${url}`)
          resolve(resopnse)
        })
      })

    })
    Cypress.Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
      // process responses
      console.log("All responses ready")
      console.log(responses.map(response => response.redirects.toString()))
    })
  })
```

- Should we use Cypress for checking the status of an external site?

I don't have the complete context of what you're doing. Apparently, it seems you're using Cypress as a monitoring tool that regularly checks the availability of some external sites and send out notifications. If so, I would say no, Cypress is a testing framework to write tests of your own services/systems.

Comment: To give a little bit more context - the purpose of those tests was to create basic smoke tests for pages (we have quite a lot of them) - to check if they are available for a user after login. Unfortunately we are unable to do it other way (e.g. lower level tests) because of legacy not-well-written system. Simplest way was to create a test per page, but while we will probably have many pages to check I was trying to find a better way to do it.

Also thank You for proving idea about *Cypress.Promise.all*!

Comment: I'm still not clear about your intention. What action do you take
- when some of these legacy sites are unavailable, aborting a deployment, notifying devops team ...?
- when all of them are fine?

Comment: The system is huge, lot of legacy code without any tests. Additionally, new functionalities are still being added and they might break some already existing functionalities (and they did once). Thats why we are trying to figure out some smoke/sanity tests that would quickly give us some feedback about state of system (besides developing functional tests at the same time).

Comment: It makes sense now. I'd suggest you have a single test file that includes all the checks of legacy services.  You can split them into a few tests so that it doesn't take too long to finish a test. Having too many tests here doesn't make much difference except for difficult maintenance

Comment: Fully agree ;) But first step was to investigate what Cypress.io has to offer :D

Comment: Cypress chainer objects aren't promises (they're not compatible with Promises/A+ at all) -- the similarity pretty much ends with them having `.then()` api. Using `Promise.all` may seem to work, but it doesn't do what you think it does. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/915. Hence my implementation of `cy.all` in my answer.

Comment: @dwelle Yep, I did run into the same problem mentioned in that github issue and found wrapping a result with Cypress.Promise resolved the problem. Initially, I thought it only affected a few use cases. However, it seems Cypress.Promise.all doesn't understand cy results.

Comment: `Cypress.Promise` is just an alias for [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/), which is `Promises/A+`-compatible, which means it's pretty much the same as native `Promise`. It does understand cy results (whatever that means), it's just that cypress chainer objects aren't `Promises/A+` and their API works differently. You're trying to integrate two incompatible APIs. Wrapping the cy commands into `new Promise` will work, but I don't see any benefit in doing this (you'll also always need to remember to do it) as opposed to what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: You should also edit your misleading initial paragraph in your answer to reflect this.

Comment: @dwelle: thanks for the explanation. I'm fully aware cy chainers are not identical to Promise and expected Cypress team should have a proper wrapper around it. Turned out, they don't have it yet.

Comment: Cypress chaining was specifically designed not to work like promises (that's why [you can't use `async/await`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1417)) and I don't expect it to change anytime soon. The fact that in userland we often [hack around it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise) (including my helper above) is a different matter.