# i can't return a response value on my cypress api call

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to make a cypress api call and get the value to be use on a next stage api call and when i make a return it just send me a big obj of commands

the call im making is

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('getSession', () => {
  cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/New`,
      headers: {
        'Client-Type': 'backend'
      }
  })
      .its('body')
      .then(json => {  
        return {
          id: json.value.props.id,
          name: json.value.props.name
        }
     }) 
    }) 

Cypress.Commands.add('createNew', (email = Cypress.env('userEmail'), password = Cypress.env('userPassword')) => {
  const session = cy.getSession()
  cy.log('api respond', session.id)
  cy.createMember(email, password, session.id)
})
```

and the response im getting is

`[$Chainer]` with a big obj

I'm not sure if the return on `.then` put it on a container but i can't find the value any when if someone can suggest what i have made wrong on the request call, that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the cypress docs:
[image]

So the `createNew` command must be rewritten to respect the async nature of cy commands.

**Using `then`**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createNew', (email = Cypress.env('userEmail'), password = Cypress.env('userPassword')) => {
  cy.getSession().then( session => {
    cy.log('api respond', session.id)
    cy.createMember(email, password, session.id)
  })
})
```

**Using aliases**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createNew', (email = Cypress.env('userEmail'), password = Cypress.env('userPassword')) => {
  cy.getSession().as("session")
  cy.get("@session").then(session => {
    cy.log('api respond', session.id)
  })
  cy.get("@session").then(session => {
    cy.createMember(email, password, session.id)
  })
```

Comment: then i can't really use the call value to make different calls, the only way is to store the value somewhere and use it later. i can't really just make a chain of calls using some of the value on different calls

Comment: because that will be limited just for one step chain, because if i want to use again the session.id on step4 then i need to pass that to step2 and step3 for me to use it on step4 .then

Comment: I've added alias option to the answer. Using aliases, you can use the value in multiple steps

Comment: can `get` call multi alias like `cy.get("@session, @newValue")` or its just limited to one per get? @Mikhail Bolotov

Comment: ok reading on docs you can only use one alias per get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298710/how-to-get-values-of-multiple-aliases-without-introducing-callback-hell-in-cypre